# Checking the text within a div using React Enzyme

Tags: enzyme

Doing a shallow rendering, I'm working with the following and trying to use the `.get()` function in order to check the text within the node. My page has multiples of the class `tag-cloud__section`. I've found that `.html` and `.text` returns an error that they are not a function. What am I misunderstanding here?

`expect(wrapper.find('.tag-cloud__section').get(0).text()).toContain('these words');`

The project I'm on is using 3.3, but I haven't seen anything mentioning in the docs that its a newer feature. Any tips, pointers or exposing of my ignorance is appreciated!

Comment: Try with `.first()` instead of `.get(0)`

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and it worked, then also found the `at(0)` method. Which allows me to run it multiple times to check and make sure that each one has the right value, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are able to use both `.first()` and `.at(0)` to perform this action